# How to get value from specify key in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this objects:

```
{label: "Name1", values: ["el0", "el1"]}
{label: "Name2", values: ["el0", "el1"]}
```

I need to catch `label` values from this object and `values` array. So i do this:

```
$.each(obj, function(index, value){ 
    if (index === "label"){
        var labels = value;
    }
    // actions with data here
});
```

If i do my actions outside of if labels var is `undefined`, can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access a property on an object, you don't need the if statement.

```
objects.forEach(function(object){
    var label = object.label;
    //do stuff with label
});
```

With regards to your posted code, `index` will always return an integer value, so it will never equal `"label"`, and `labels` will never be given a value. Javascript scopes things according to functions, so the variable `labels` is accessible anywhere in the callback of the `each` method.

It's even accessible before it's defined, due to variable hoisting, though the value is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var labels = null;
$.each(obj, function(index, value){ 
    if (index === "label"){
        labels = value;
    }
    // actions with data here
    // now you can use "labels" variable anywhere, 
    // because it has a global scope.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need `array.push` for this i guess

```
var labels = [];
for (var i in obj)
    labels.push(obj[i].label);
console.log(labels);
```

Answer (score 0):

insted use $.each, try access the label attribute directly.

```
var labels = obj['label'];
```

or

```
var labels = obj.label;
```

If what you have is an array. try this.

```
var labels =[];
$.each(objs, function(i, item){
    labels.push(item.label);
});
```